# Off-centre circle given a radius in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to come up with the polar equation for an off-centre circle that has a certain radius. I've found a [lecture handout](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-4-techniques-of-integration/part-c-parametric-equations-and-polar-coordinates/session-82-polar-coordinates/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses82d.pdf) (pdf) in which the equation is derived for a circle that is off-centre by exactly its radius.

I tried a similar strategy by going from Cartesian to polar coordinates like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
&r^2 = (x - x_0)^2 + y^2 \\
\iff& r^2 = x^2 - 2 \cdot x_0 \cdot x + x_0^2 + y^2 \quad \wedge x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \\
\iff& 0 = - 2 \cdot x_0 \cdot x + x_0^2 \quad \wedge x = r \cdot \cos(\theta) \\
\iff& x_0^2 = 2 \cdot x_0 \cdot r \cdot \cos(\theta) \\
\iff& r = \frac{x_0}{2 \cdot \cos(\theta)}
\end{align*}
$$

But when I try to plot this in Desmos, it yields a vertical line through $x=x_0$.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this even possible?

Comment: Try taking something of the form $$ R^2 = (x-x_0)^2 + y^2 $$ for a constant $R$ and using the regular polar transformation

$$ x=r\cos{\theta} $$
$$ y=r\sin{\theta} $$

Comment: In your second line you're solving 2 simultaneous equations,. That is, the points of intersection between $r^2 = x^2 - 2xx_0 +x_0^2 + y^2$ (which is the equation you are working on) and $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ (which is a completely different circle).

Comment: Oh, of course! Thanks for the comments, I'll leave the question up just in case.